# Is this a joint distribution? Trying pdf and cdf

Tags: probability, solution-verification

> Is the following function
>
> $F(x,y) = 1 - e^{-xy}$ for $x,y \ge 0$
>
> $F(x,y)= 0 $ otherwise
>
> a joint distribution function for two random variables X and Y ? Provide
> reasons.

This is my homework problem. I'm not sure if he means CDF or PDF. I integrated the function $\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty F(x,y)\space dx \space dy$ [in Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+infinity+%28integral+from+0+to+infinity+%281-e%5E%28-xy%29%29+dx%29+dy) and it doesn't converge (not surprising because the constant term 1 blows up). So it's not a PDF.

If it's a CDF then taking $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = e^{-xy}(1-xy)$ gives  the alleged PDF, but integrating it $\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-xy}(1-xy) \space dx \space dy$ [in Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+0+to+infinity+%28integral+0+to+infinity+%281+-+x+y%29%2FE%5E%28x+y%29+dx%29+dy) yields 0. So either way that's not a PDF.

So either way the original F is not a joing distribution function.

Is this accurate? Are these valid tests? Is there a different sense of "joint distribution function" other than CDF and PDF to test for?

Comment: You do not have to derive it to verify wether or not it is a CDF. Use the definition : $F(x, y) = P(X \le x, Y \le y)$ for some r.v.s $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: @Olivier Thanks for your time. I'm not sure what you mean. Is my argument invalid?

Comment: For the CDF test, yes. You simply have to verify that $F$ is a probability (some conditions here) that increases with $x$ and $y$.

Comment: [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1172854/75923) could help.

Comment: @Olivier I think you missed a link in your comment on "here"

Comment: I meant conditions for $F$ being a probability. Note that you have $\int_0^a \int_0^b e^{-xy}(1-xy) \space dx \space dy = F(a, b)$. Take the limit as $a$ and $b$ goes to infinity... This does not, however, prove that $F$ is a CDF. Your argument would be valid otherwise.

Comment: @Olivier I'm sorry I'm a little confused. You said "This does not, however, prove that F is a CDF." Doesn't what I wrote prove that F is NOT a CDF because the integral when a,b go to infinity does NOT equal 1?

Comment: The integral is in fact equal to 1. Take the limit of $F(a, b)$ as $a$ and $b$ goes to infinity and you get 1. I don't know why wolfram gave 0 as an answer. You can plot $1-e^{-xy}$ if you have trouble visualizing it.

Answer (score 1):

If they say "distribution function" that means CDF. If they meant PDF they would say "density function".

The given function is NOT a valid distribution function.

First check that $\lim_{x,y \to -\infty}{F(x,y)} = 0$ and that $\lim_{x,y \to \infty}{F(x,y)} = 1$. That's OK in this case.

$F$ is a continuous function so it must have a density function given by $f(x,y) := \dfrac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x\partial y}$.

Check that $f(x,y) \geq 0$ for all $x,y$.

If this holds then $F$ is a joint distribution function.

You found $f(x,y) = e^{-xy}(1-xy)$. This is negative when $xy\gt 1$. Therefore, $f$ is not a density function and so $F$ is not a distribution function.